# problem data recovery with axios and vue cal (scheluder)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I need to get data with axios and send them to my calendar with the 'splitDays' table and I have to change the variable name of my data to put "class" and "label"

I can recover my data but when I leave the axios I go to undefined

```
data() {
            return {
                splitDays:[], // :splitDays

            };
        },


mounted() {
            axios
            .get(`${process.env.*****}/users?role=***&active=***`)
            .then(response => ( this.users = response.data,
            console.log(this.users)
            ))
            console.log(this.users)
            /*
                for (let splitDayIndex in mySplitDays){
                    let splitDay= mySplitDays[splitDayIndex]
                    splitDay.class = splitDay.lastname
                    splitDay.label = splitDay.lastname
                    mySplitDays[splitDayIndex]=splitDay
                }
            */
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by *when I leave the axios I go to undefined*, but your second `console.log(...)` will be executed before your axios call finishes. Try with:

```
data() {
            return {
                splitDays:[], // :splitDays

            };
        },


async mounted() {
            let response = await axios
               .get(`${process.env.AFFECTIT_API}/users?role=Collaborateur&active=1`)
            this.users = response.data

            console.log(this.users)
            /*
                for (let splitDayIndex in mySplitDays){
                    let splitDay= mySplitDays[splitDayIndex]
                    splitDay.class = splitDay.lastname
                    splitDay.label = splitDay.lastname
                    mySplitDays[splitDayIndex]=splitDay
                }
            */
            },
```

Comment: now i have this error : ReferenceError: mySplitDays is not defined when i use my "for" and the error : [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: That's another issue and it would be better to create a different question for it. Maybe if you rewrite your `for` to: `for (let splitDayIndex in this.splitDays){` works, though.

Comment: ok but this is not this.. and i can't create a new questions...

Comment: what do you mean by *this is not this*? and why can't you create a different question?

Comment: i have change with "this.mySplitDays" but not work.. because i'm a new users..

Comment: I upvoted your question, so perhaps you can post new questions now. Yeah, `this.mySplitDays` won't work, because you don't have `mySplitDays` defined in the `data()` function. You have `splitDays` defined there (notice the lack of the "my" prefix in it).

Comment: No i have change this too ^^ i have this error : [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "ReferenceError: mySplitDays is not defined"
 and : [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: @Alexis, this is a totally separate issue than your original question. Feel free to accept/upvote my answer as the solution and other answers to your previous questions, so you'll rack up some points and be able to create a different question with your new issue.